# PHP Compare item in two array?

Tags: php, compare

I tried many times compare but not work.

I have also tried to use array_diff or array_intersect but ...

```
 $a = array(
            array('1','11'),
            array('2','22'),
            array('3','33'),
            array('4','44'),
    );

$b = array(
    array('2','22'),
    array('3','33')
);

for($j = 0;$j < count($a);$j++) {
    for($v = 0;$v < count($b);$v++) {
        if($b[$v][0] == $a[$j][0]) {
           echo 1.' ';
        } else {
            echo 0.' ';
        }
    }
}
```

result:

> 0 1 1 0

Comment: You will need to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you can't get `4` echos `0 1 1 0` because you are running loop of loop which gives you `8` echo values printed (eg: `0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0`).

Answer (score 1):

Your current script returns

```
  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

To get your desired output you should try :

```
foreach ($a as $v)
{
    in_array($v, $b) ? print("1 ") : print("0 ");
}
```

Output

```
0 1 1 0
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.org/MC6h5cFM)